# Spark isnt pushing Filters/Partitions i.e PushedFilters and PartitionFilter are empty)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Spark Version : 2.4.4

Data is partitioned on `date_col` column

1st Example :

```
df.filter("datetime_col >= current_timestamp - interval 48 hours and date_col >= date_format(current_timestamp - interval 48 hours,"yyyyMMdd")")
```

For the above Dataframe Filter, in the Physical Plan -

```
..., PartitionCount: 31, PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(date_col#245), (date_col#245 >= 20210929)], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(datetime_col), GreaterThanOrEqual(datetime_col,2021-09-29 07:16:18.706)] .....
```

So in this scenario , the PartitionFilter and PushedFilter both are present thereby enhancing the performance as they will be pushed down and the data will be smaller in the first place.

2nd Example :

```
df.filter("(datetime_col >= current_timestamp - interval 48 hours and date_col >= date_format(current_timestamp - interval 48 hours,"yyyyMMdd")) 
or ((datetime_col >= current_timestamp - interval 60 hours and date_col >= date_format(current_timestamp - interval 60 hours,"yyyyMMdd")))")
```

In this case , the Physical plan doesn't have any PushedFilter and PartitionFilters.

```
....PartitionCount: 1821, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], R....
```

Values of Related Parquet Confs. -

```
"spark.sql.parquet.filterPushdown", "true" 
"spark.sql.optimizer.nestedSchemaPruning.enabled","false"
```

I dont understand why is this happening.

The only difference between the both examples is the fact that in the 1st Example , I am filtering with just 1 date filter, but in the 2nd example there are 2 filters being applied on the dataframe.

Besides My Idea was , in the 2nd example , I am applying a filter where `date_col >= 20210929  or date_col >= 20210928` , which can be simplified as - `date_col >= 20210928` i.e the lower value.

Thanks in Advance.